# Whats the best/safest way to run an async method on pageload?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have an async method which loads data from disk (using Json).

However, when I run the method in StartupPage() or OnNavigatedTo() I can't use the await operator as these aren't async methods.  The code will still run, but I get warnings that it isn't 'awaited'.

Is there a good way of running an async method on startup/navigatedto?

Comment: append Result after call to method like someMethodAsync().Result;

Comment: @Aaron, that will deadlock the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `async` on `OnNavigatedTo()` to avoid warning ..

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            await App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - ive added this to my method

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to start async method at the initialization, but you must be sure that your initialization workflow is not broken by the async call.

A warning about not awaited async method call can be suppressed by the #pragma or by a ContinueWith call. I prefer the last one to suppress this warning, please investigate the following code of the extension method.

```
public static void LogAsyncError(this Task task, [LocalizationRequired(false)] string message = null)
{
    if (task == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var log = Logger.Create("Task error logger");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            log.Error(t.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error(message, t.Exception);
        }
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

So now you can call async methods without warning and with an error logging.

```
SomeMethodAsync().LogAsyncError();
```